DRL Agent is getting stuck on the lower bound of my action space
I'm new to DRL and I've set up an env for an RIS assisted CoMP-NOMA network (this is unimportant I believe) but there's a function here that gives me some "rates". I'm supposed to be optimizing the sum of these rates. Now one of these is an edge rate - being the smaller value and the other is the centre rate - being the larger value. So my reward function is set up kinda like this:
def comp_reward(self, rate_edge, rates_near):
        # Normalize the rates by their respective thresholds
        normalized_rate_edge = rate_edge / self.t_edge_norm
        normalized_rate_near = rates_near[0] / self.t_near_norm
        
        # Compute the average normalized rate
        normalized_Rsum = (normalized_rate_edge + normalized_rate_near)
      
        # Calculate a continuous negative reward
        continuous_penalty = -15  # Constant negative reward

        # If the thresholds are met, give a large reward
        if rate_edge >= self.threshold_edge and rates_near[0] >= self.threshold_near:
            large_reward = 1000  # Example large reward for meeting thresholds
        else:
            large_reward = 0

        # Reward function with penalty for extreme allocations and a large reward for meeting thresholds
        reward = continuous_penalty + normalized_Rsum + large_reward

        return reward

Basically I'm making it so that unless a certain threshold is reached, a continous penalty is awarded and therefore and once this is reached, a large reward is awarded and the episode ends. Now the problem that I'm running into is as follows:
I have to optimize two factors, one known as the Power Allocation factor (a value between 0 and 1) and a Phase Shifts (100 Elements between 0 and 1). Now despite a continous negative reward and it exploring (sometimes) and reaching the goal and getting the large positive reward, it keeps getting stuck at the lower bound of the Power Allocation which is 0.5. I don't understand why this is happening since hypothetically it should be going in the direction of the reward.
I've tried a bunch of things ranging from a function where the reward is a sum of the two rates (normalized for equal weightages), giving a penalty for edge allocations, giving my channel gains in observation as regular, norm and log-norm, having the observation space comprise of everything ranging from just my channel gains, channel gains + allocations + phase shifts + rate sums and everything in between. Here's my channel code - I know it's bad code but that's because I've been LOSING my mind trying to figure out why this is happening with no help.
Environment:
import numpy as np
import gymnasium as gym
from gymnasium import spaces
from comyx.network import Link
from comyx.utils import dbm2pow, db2pow
from comyx.propagation import get_noise_power

class WirelessEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, BS1, UC1, UE, R1, links_near, links_edge, N0, bandwidth, K, threshold_edge=2.2, threshold_near=10, decay_rate=0.99, testing_mode=False, maintain_steps=10):
        super(WirelessEnv, self).__init__()
        
        self.BS1 = BS1
        self.UC1 = UC1
        self.UE = UE
        self.R1 = R1
        self.links_near = links_near
        self.links_edge = links_edge
        self.N0 = N0
        self.bandwidth = bandwidth
        self.K = K
        self.testing_mode = testing_mode
        self.Pt = 10  # Fixed power level in dBm
        self.Pt_lin = dbm2pow(self.Pt)  # Convert to Watt
        self.N0_lin = dbm2pow(self.N0)  # Convert to Watt
        
        self.gains_near = None
        self.gains_edge = None
        self.mc = 100000  # Number of channel realizations
        self.n_elements = self.R1.n_elements
        self.shape_ris = (self.n_elements,)  # Correct shape for phase shifts
        # Correct the action space to match the expected number of elements
        self.action_space = spaces.Box(
            low=np.concatenate((-np.pi * np.ones(self.shape_ris), [0.5])),
            high=np.concatenate((np.pi * np.ones(self.shape_ris), [1.0])),
            dtype=np.float64
        )
        # Update observation space to handle negative values from log
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(self.n_elements + 3,), dtype=np.float64)
        
        self.realization_idx = 0 # Initialize with a default realization index

        # Performance thresholds and decay rate
        self.threshold_edge = threshold_edge
        self.threshold_near = threshold_near
        self.t_edge_norm = self.threshold_edge
        self.t_near_norm = self.threshold_near
        self.decay_rate = decay_rate
        self.current_step = 0
        self.episode_number = 0  # Initialize episode counter

        # Counter for maintaining performance
        self.maintain_steps = maintain_steps
        self.performance_counter = 0

    def calculate_sinr_allocation_multiple(self, P_t, gains_near, gains_edge, N0_lin, allocation):
        # Power allocated to near and edge users
        power_near = allocation["UEn"] * P_t
        power_edge = allocation["UEf"] * P_t
        
        # SINR for the edge user (UE)
        sinr_edge = (power_edge * np.abs(gains_edge)**2) / (power_near * np.abs(gains_edge)**2 + N0_lin)
        rate_edge = np.log2(1 + sinr_edge)
        
        # SINR for the near user (UC1)
        sinr_near = (power_near * np.abs(gains_near)**2) / N0_lin
        rates_near = np.log2(1 + sinr_near)
        return rate_edge, rates_near

    def recalculate_gains(self, realization_idx):
        self.gains_near = []
        self.gains_edge = []

        current_amplitudes = self.R1.amplitudes[:, realization_idx]
        reflection_matrix = np.diag(current_amplitudes * np.exp(1j * self.R1.phase_shifts))

        gain_eff_near = self.links_near[0].channel_gain[..., realization_idx] + \
                        (self.links_near[1].channel_gain[..., realization_idx].T @ reflection_matrix @ self.links_near[2].channel_gain[..., realization_idx])
        self.gains_near.append(gain_eff_near)
        
        gain_eff_edge = self.links_edge[0].channel_gain[..., realization_idx] + \
                        (self.links_edge[1].channel_gain[..., realization_idx].T @ reflection_matrix @ self.links_edge[2].channel_gain[..., realization_idx])
        self.gains_edge.append(gain_eff_edge)

        self.gains_near = np.array(self.gains_near)
        self.gains_edge = np.array(self.gains_edge)
    def comp_reward(self, rate_edge, rates_near):
        # Normalize the rates by their respective thresholds
        normalized_rate_edge = rate_edge / self.t_edge_norm
        normalized_rate_near = rates_near[0] / self.t_near_norm
        
        # Compute the average normalized rate
        normalized_Rsum = (normalized_rate_edge + normalized_rate_near)
        
        # Indicator functions for QoS constraints using static thresholds
        # ζu_edge = 1 if rate_edge < self.threshold_edge else 0
        # ζu_near = 1 if rates_near[0] < self.threshold_near else 0
        # QoS_violations = (ζu_edge + ζu_near) / 2  # Average of the indicator functions
        
        # Calculate a continuous negative reward
        continuous_penalty = -15  # Constant negative reward

        # If the thresholds are met, give a large reward
        if rate_edge >= self.threshold_edge and rates_near[0] >= self.threshold_near:
            large_reward = 1000  # Example large reward for meeting thresholds
        else:
            large_reward = 0

        # Reward function with penalty for extreme allocations and a large reward for meeting thresholds
        reward = continuous_penalty + normalized_Rsum + large_reward

        return reward

    def step(self, action):
        self.current_step += 1
        # Ensure the action array has the expected number of elements (101 elements)
        assert len(action) == self.n_elements + 1, f"Expected action size {self.n_elements + 1}, got {len(action)}"
        # Separate the phase shifts and power allocation from the action
        phase_shift_action = action[:-1]  # Keep as 1D array of 100 elements
        self.R1.phase_shifts = phase_shift_action  # Set phase shifts direct
        self.allocation_far = action[-1]  # Last element is power allocation
        if self.testing_mode == True:
            realization_idx = np.random.choice(self.mc)
            self.recalculate_gains(realization_idx)
        else:
            self.recalculate_gains(self.realization_idx)  # Using single realization for the current episode

        allocation = {
            "UEn": 1 - self.allocation_far,
            "UEf": self.allocation_far
        }

        rate_edge, rates_near = self.calculate_sinr_allocation_multiple(
            self.Pt_lin, self.gains_near, self.gains_edge, self.N0_lin, allocation
        )

        log_norm_gain_uc1 = np.log(np.linalg.norm(self.gains_near))
        log_norm_gain_ue = np.log(np.linalg.norm(self.gains_edge))

        rates_sum = rates_near + rate_edge
        reward = self.comp_reward(rate_edge, rates_near)  # Calculate reward using comp_reward

        # Ensure all components are flattened or converted to 1D arrays
        phase_shifts_flat = self.R1.phase_shifts.flatten()
        allocation_far = np.array([self.allocation_far])
        log_norm_gain_uc1 = np.array([log_norm_gain_uc1])
        log_norm_gain_ue = np.array([log_norm_gain_ue])
        rates_sum = np.array([rates_sum])

        # Concatenate the phase shifts and other components to form the observation
        observation = np.concatenate((
            phase_shifts_flat,
            allocation_far.flatten(),
            log_norm_gain_uc1.flatten(),
            log_norm_gain_ue.flatten(),
        ))
        print(f"Episode: {self.episode_number}, Step: {self.current_step}")
        print("Edge Rate:", rate_edge)
        print("Near Rate:", rates_near[0])
        print("Reward:", reward)
        print("Power Alloc:", self.allocation_far)
        terminated = False

        # Update performance counter
        if (rate_edge >= self.threshold_edge) and (rates_near[0] >= self.threshold_near):
            self.performance_counter += 1
            if self.performance_counter >= self.maintain_steps:
                terminated = True
        else:
            self.performance_counter = 0  # Reset the counter if criteria are not met

        if self.threshold_edge < 1.6 or self.threshold_near < 6:
            self.decay_rate = 1
        # Apply decay to thresholds
        self.threshold_edge *= self.decay_rate
        self.threshold_near *= self.decay_rate

        truncated = False  # Add truncated flag
        info = {}  # Add info dictionary

        return observation, float(reward), terminated, truncated, info

    def reset(self, seed=None):
        self.current_step = 0
        self.episode_number += 1  # Increment episode counter
        self.performance_counter = 0  # Reset the performance counter
        self.R1.phase_shifts = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, self.shape_ris)
        self.allocation_far = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1)
        self.realization_idx = np.random.randint(self.mc)  # Select a random realization index for the episode

        self.recalculate_gains(self.realization_idx)  # Using the selected realization

        log_norm_gain_uc1 = (np.linalg.norm(self.gains_near))
        log_norm_gain_ue = (np.linalg.norm(self.gains_edge))

        rates_sum = 0  # Initial rates_sum is zero

        # Ensure all components are flattened or converted to 1D arrays
        phase_shifts_flat = self.R1.phase_shifts.flatten()
        allocation_far = np.array([self.allocation_far])
        log_norm_gain_uc1 = np.array([log_norm_gain_uc1])
        log_norm_gain_ue = np.array([log_norm_gain_ue])
        rates_sum = np.array([rates_sum])

        # Concatenate the phase shifts and other components to form the observation
        observation = np.concatenate((
            phase_shifts_flat,
            allocation_far.flatten(),
            log_norm_gain_uc1.flatten(),
            log_norm_gain_ue.flatten(),
        ))
        info = {}  # Add info dictionary

        # Reset the thresholds to their initial values
        self.threshold_edge = self.t_edge_norm
        self.threshold_near = self.t_near_norm

        return observation, info


Here's my Training Script:
import numpy as np
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.env_checker import check_env
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import BaseCallback, CallbackList
from tqdm import tqdm
from Env import WirelessEnv  # Ensure this imports your WirelessEnv class
from comyx.network import BaseStation, UserEquipment, RIS, Link
from comyx.propagation import get_noise_power
from comyx.utils import dbm2pow, db2pow, generate_seed
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
\Pt = np.linspace(-40, 20, 80)  # dBm
Pt_lin = dbm2pow(Pt)  # Watt
bandwidth = 1e6  # Bandwidth in Hz
frequency = 2.4e9  # Carrier frequency
temperature = 300  # Kelvin
mc = 100000  # Number of channel realizations
K = 3  # Rician factor

N0 = get_noise_power(temperature, bandwidth)  # dBm
N0_lin = dbm2pow(N0)  # Watt

n_antennas = 1
n_elements = 100

nlos_fading_args = {"type": "nakagami", "m": 1, "omega": 1}
los_fading_args = {"type": "nakagami", "m": 2, "omega": 1}

bu_pathloss_args = {
    "type": "reference",
    "alpha": 3,
    "p0": 30,
    "frequency": frequency,
}  # p0 is the reference power in dBm

br_pathloss_args = {"type": "reference", "alpha": 2.7, "p0": 30, "frequency": frequency}
ru_pathloss_args = {"type": "reference", "alpha": 2.7, "p0": 30, "frequency": frequency}
BS1 = BaseStation("BS", position=[0, 0, 10], n_antennas=n_antennas, t_power=Pt_lin)
UC1 = UserEquipment("UC1", position=[30, 30, 1], n_antennas=n_antennas)
R1 = RIS("RIS", position=[15, 15, 5], n_elements=n_elements)
UE = UserEquipment("UE", position=[120, 10, 1], n_antennas=n_antennas)

shape_ris = (n_elements, mc)

R1.phase_shifts = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, shape_ris)
R1.amplitudes = np.ones(shape_ris)
shape_bu = (n_antennas, n_antennas, mc)
shape_br = (n_elements, n_antennas, mc)
shape_ru = (n_elements, n_antennas, mc)

# Links
link_bs1_ue = Link(
    BS1, UE,
    nlos_fading_args, bu_pathloss_args,
    shape=shape_bu, seed=generate_seed("BS1-UE"),
)

link_ris1_ue = Link(
    R1, UE,
    los_fading_args, ru_pathloss_args,
    shape=shape_br, seed=generate_seed("RIS1-UE"),
    rician_args={"K": db2pow(K), "order": "pre"},
)

link_bs1_ris1 = Link(
    BS1, R1,
    los_fading_args, br_pathloss_args,
    shape=shape_br, seed=generate_seed("BS1-RIS1"),
    rician_args={"K": db2pow(K), "order": "post"},
)

link_bs1_uc1 = Link(
    BS1, UC1,
    nlos_fading_args, bu_pathloss_args,
    shape=shape_bu, seed=generate_seed("BS1-UC1"),
)

link_ris1_uc1 = Link(
    R1, UC1,
    los_fading_args, ru_pathloss_args,
    shape=shape_br, seed=generate_seed("RIS1-UC1"),
    rician_args={"K": db2pow(K), "order": "pre"},
)

links_near = [link_bs1_uc1, link_ris1_uc1, link_bs1_ris1]
links_edge = [link_bs1_ue, link_ris1_ue, link_bs1_ris1]

# Instantiate the environment
env = WirelessEnv(BS1, UC1, UE, R1, links_near, links_edge, N0, bandwidth, K, threshold_edge=1.0, threshold_near=2.0, decay_rate=0.99)

class RewardCallback(BaseCallback):
    def __init__(self, window_size=100):
        super().__init__()
        self.rewards = []
        self.moving_avg = []
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.episode_num = 0

    def _on_step(self):
        if self.locals['dones']:
            self.rewards.append(self.locals['rewards'])
            if len(self.rewards) >= self.window_size:
                avg = sum(self.rewards[-self.window_size:]) / self.window_size
                self.moving_avg.append(avg)
            self.episode_num += 1
            print(f"Episode {self.episode_num}, Reward: {self.locals['rewards']}")
        return True

    def plot_rewards(self):
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
        plt.plot(self.rewards, alpha=0.3, label='Raw Rewards')
        plt.plot(self.moving_avg, label=f'{self.window_size}-Episode Moving Average')
        plt.xlabel('Episodes')
        plt.ylabel('Rewards')
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()

class TqdmCallback(BaseCallback):
    def __init__(self, tqdm_bar, verbose=0):
        super(TqdmCallback, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.tqdm_bar = tqdm_bar

    def _on_step(self) -> bool:
        self.tqdm_bar.update(1)
        return True
def linear_schedule(initial_value):
    def func(progress_remaining):
        return progress_remaining * initial_value
    return func
# Set the initial learning rate
initial_learning_rate = 3e-4
ent_coef = 0.01  # Increase to encourage more exploration
clip_range = 0.3  # Increase to allow for larger updates
n_envs = 1  # Use multiple environments for diverse experiences

env = WirelessEnv(BS1, UC1, UE, R1, links_near, links_edge, N0, bandwidth, K)

model = PPO(
    "MlpPolicy", 
    env, 
    verbose=1, 
    device='cuda', 
    learning_rate=linear_schedule(initial_learning_rate), 
    ent_coef=ent_coef, 
    clip_range=clip_range, 
    n_steps=2048
)

check_env(env)

reward_callback = RewardCallback()

total_timesteps = 300000
with tqdm(total=total_timesteps, desc="Training Progress") as pbar:
    model.learn(total_timesteps=total_timesteps, callback=CallbackList([TqdmCallback(pbar), reward_callback]))

model.save("ppo_basestation")

reward_callback.plot_rewards()

Please help.
